# Creating an Access database with a specific encoding scheme

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

Can I create an Access database with a specific encoding scheme like UTF-8, ANSI, or Greek? If I don't specify an encoding scheme what will Access use?

Comment: Please show some research - have you done any searching, and if so, what did you find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current versions of Access will always store text internally as Unicode, so there is no way to create an Access database that uses a particular character set.

However, Access does offer the option to create databases that use different sort orders (collation sequences) for different languages, e.g., Greek, Italian, Russian, etc.. For more information see

[Specify the default language sort order](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/specify-the-default-language-sort-order-mdb-HP005187510.aspx)